# Godot - get_node: Node not Found - GDScript

Tags: nodes, godot, gdscript

Please help! I keep getting this error message when I run my code for a title page for my game! I'm quite new to Godot. Here's the scene tree:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEv7I.png)

TitleScreen - Control Node

```
- ColorRect - ColorRect Node
- Menu - VBoxContainer Node
    - Label - Label Node
    - Buttons - VBoxContainer Node
        - PlayButton - Button Node
        - QuitButton - Button Node
- Fade - ColorRect
```

Here is the GDScript code connected to both the PlayButton and the QuitButton:

```
extends Button

export(String) var scene_to_load
export(bool) var quit

func _ready():
    for button in $Menu/Buttons.get_children():
        button.connect("pressed", self, "_on_button_pressed", [button.scene_to_load])

func _on_button_pressed():
    get_tree().change_scene(scene_to_load)
```

When I run said Scene I get:

**get_node: Node not Found: Menu/Buttons**

Any Help would be appreciated :)

Thank you for your help with solving my problem!
[My Title Screen After being fixed :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VW8gw.png)

My game
[Game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08Gcu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you've connected the GDScript code to each `Button`, but it looks like you should have the script connected to the `TitleScreen` instead as `$Menu` is a child of `TitleScreen` and not `Button`.

You'll need to fix the script also to `extend Control` instead of `extend Button` as it is currently

**Edit**

Honestly though, if you just want to load a particular scene from a button press and nothing else you can simply change the scene directly from the button - this is just a script change

```
extends Button

export(String) var scene_to_load
export(bool) var quit

func _ready():   
    self.connect("pressed", self, "_on_button_pressed")

func _on_button_pressed():
    get_tree().change_scene(scene_to_load)
```

Comment: How can I get the scene_to_load  be for each of the buttons? I added a new script that just ads the variables for each button (Quit(bool) and scene_to_load) but now scene_to_load is not defined, but I want it to be specific for each button.

Comment: if you just want to load a particular scene from a button press and nothing else you can simply change the scene directly from the button (see edit)

Comment: The identifier "button" isn't declared in the current scope... Again, I'm quite new to this sorry.

Comment: oops let me fix that - change `button` to `self`

Comment: Thank you so much, thank you so, so, so much